# Why document.execCommand("copy") doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following [Page](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54686:2)

- When I click "**Click Here To Copy**", it calls document.execCommand("copy") to copy some text to the clipboard and it works.
- However, when I hit the button "**Open popup**", it opens a div in the same page (no iframe), then when clicking on "**Click Here To Copy**", **document.execCommand("copy") doesn't work**.

Steps to reproduce :

**document.execCommand("copy") works** :

[image]

However if I open the popup, **document.execCommand("copy") doesn't work**

[image]

Does anyone know the reason for that please ?

Thanks
cheers,

Here is my entire code :

```
    function CopyToClipBoard(d){        
        var c=document.createElement("textarea");
        c.innerText=d;
        document.body.appendChild(c);       
        
        c.select();
        document.execCommand("copy");
        document.body.removeChild(c);
    }

   <div onclick="CopyToClipBoard('text to be copied')">Click Here To copy</div>
```

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Comment: I provided the reproducible example. What is missing ?

Comment: questions should be self contained. There is no html in question

Comment: I'm using Oracle Apex which generates entire pages. Anyway thanks. Does anyone else have an idea ? Is there something related to overlay, focus, z-index ?

Comment: Try setting value of the textaraea instead of text

Comment: I've tried that. But unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: Is the function getting called?

Comment: yes it's beign called

Comment: I've added an alert showing that the function is beign called https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=54686:2

Answer (score 2):

Here is the cause of the problem :

The following code doesn't seem to work when there is an overlay of a document. For example when the caller is on a div with higher z-index or something... I'm not sure on what exactly causes this code to fail. But it seems related to overlayers, focusable elements or something... The fact is that, when the body of the document is hidden, the created text area is unable to focus and it doesn't work.

```
function CopyToClipBoard(d){        
    var c=document.createElement("textarea");
    c.innerText=d;
    document.body.appendChild(c);       
    
    c.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(c);
}

<div onclick="CopyToClipBoard('text to be copied')">Click Here To copy</div>
```

Solution :

Instead of adding the text area to the body of the document, it can be added to the caller itself... Hence it will always be in the foreground. This assumes the text to copy is short such that the execution is fast enough for the user not to notice the creation and the removal of the text area...

```
        function CopyToClipBoard(item, d){  
                var c=document.createElement("textarea");
                c.value=d;
                c.style.maxWidth = '0px';
                c.style.maxHeight = '0px';
                item.appendChild(c);

                c.focus();        
                c.select();
                document.execCommand("copy");
                item.removeChild(c);
        }


        <div onclick="CopyToClipBoard(this,'text to be copied')">Click Here To copy</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working example of `copyTextToClipboard` function. Please try to add `textArea.focus` call.

```
    const fallbackCopyTextToClipboard = text => {
      const textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
      textArea.value = text;
      textArea.style.position = 'fixed';
      document.body.appendChild(textArea);
      textArea.focus();
      textArea.select();
      document.execCommand('copy');
      document.body.removeChild(textArea);
    }
    
    const copyTextToClipboard = text => {
      if (navigator.clipboard) {
        return navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
      }
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fallbackCopyTextToClipboard(text);
        resolve();
      });
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It does not seem to work when the body of the document is hidden...

Comment: When there is something in the foreground (a div with a higher z-index or for instance or something else...), the text area is added to the body but can not select. Hence the copy doesn't work. The solution would be not adding the text area to the body of the document, but to the caller it self such that it will always be in the foreground and can select. I posted the solution....